# dynamic bind to a resource but in a state animation

Tags: wpf, binding

I have defined a visual state in which a button has a glow effect.
But I want to have a variable BlurRadius in that state.
My approach was adding a resource and change that resource in code behind.
But changes doesn't affect the visual controls.

here is xaml code :

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" x:Class="blend1.question"
    Title="question" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <System:Double x:Key="d1">10</System:Double>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                        </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome.Effect>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="mySG">
                                <VisualState x:Name="sMouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadius)" Storyboard.TargetName="Chrome">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource d1}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth)" Storyboard.TargetName="Chrome">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Chrome">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="sMouseOut">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadius)" Storyboard.TargetName="Chrome">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth)" Storyboard.TargetName="Chrome">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="1">
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16.4,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" >
        <Button.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" ShadowDepth="0" Color="Red"/>
        </Button.Effect>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                <ei:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=button}" StateName="sMouseOver"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                <ei:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=button}" StateName="sMouseOut"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="increase" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,8,30.8,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

and here is the code behind :

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for question.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class question : Window
{
    public question()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
        double d= (double)Resources["d1"];
        Resources["d1"]=d+10;
        MessageBox.Show(Resources["d1"].ToString());
    }
}
```

How should I dynamic bind to a resource in a state ? and what about the condition in which I use a DependencyProperty in my window class for varying BlurRadius ? and If there is another logical approach let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not necessary to answer all of those questions just give me a solution and it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was impossible. :)

Thanks for all who contributed to this answer.